# Why does Sequel Pro have to connect to MAMP (or any other mySQL provider)

Tags: mysql, mamp, sequelpro

I thought Sequel Pro allows you to upload .sql and data so why must it be connected to MAMP for example? Am I missing some very basic point here?

Comment: Where would you expect it to upload SQL and data without a database instance for that SQL to be used and the data to be stored? *Why do I need an internet connection in order to browse the web with Chrome? Chrome is a web browser, right?*  Tools designed to make it easier to use a DBMS still require a DBMS to be there to be used. Sequel Pro is a tool used to work with a database, but there still has to be a database somewhere.

Comment: Thanks - so basically it's a visual tool to help better see your data (and that data is held in mySQL, in my instance MAMP) - that right?

Comment: Works for me as a description. :-)